# Wiki/Collaboration software: TWiki vs. XWiki vs. MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

As the title suggests, I'm interested in which of these Wikis is the best solution to use.

I'm concerned with:

- Features the page editor provides (not all users will be keen on learning new syntax);
- LDAP/AD support;
- The way privileges are set for users (or users in groups?);
- Documents and multimedia files support;
- Ease and flexibility for theming the Wiki.

All opinions are taken in consideration..

Comment: It would be nicer if you had set some criteria, the question as is can't really be answered. All those areas are worked on by pretty much all wikis, except LDAP.
As you didn't get an answer for MediaWiki: yes, it supports LDAP too. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all these features are readily available in XWiki. I don't know enough about the other 2 wikis you cite though.

The http://xwiki.org web site provides more information. If you don't find something in the documentation you can ask on the XWiki forum/list and you'll get some fast answers:
dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/MailingLists

Thanks
-Vincent (XWiki committer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vincent! I'll be looking into XWiki these days (and upvote your answer when I have >15 reputation :))

Answer (score 3):

If you go here http://www.wikimatrix.org/compare/MediaWiki+TWiki+XWiki you can see all the features side by side.

It answers these questions easily:

- Features the page editor provides (not all users will be keen on learning new syntax);
- LDAP/AD support;
- Ease and flexibility for theming the Wiki.

You might need to do more digging for these:

- The way privileges are set for users (or users in groups?);
- Documents and multimedia files support;